# How to iterate over array with whole numbers, while adding fractions - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
var arr = [1, 4, 1, 5, 1];
var fractionSum; 

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 

  fractionSum += arr[i] / arr.length 

}

console.log(fractionSum) = NaN
```

Why is it NaN?  How do I make this work the way I intended it to work which is to convert each item in the array to a fraction and add them up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify a start value for adding up the values. Otherwise you have a value of `undefined` and any numerical operation returns [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), which means not a number.

```
var fractionSum = 0;
```

Comment: Shoot, totally forgot!  Thanks Nina.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Array.reduce`, like so:

```
const fractionSum = arr.reduce((p, c) => p + c/arr.length, 0)
```